# HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL -java servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets

i am having trouble getting the page to work, what i am doing is when i click the link it should connect to the database and display the data to the browser.

this is my jsp code:

```
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

       </head>
       <body>
       <%  
          String str = (String)request.getAttribute("acId");
        %>
        Account ID: <a href="detailsservlet"> <%= str %>
       </body>
       </html>
```

this is my servlet code:

```
       package com.Project.Hdfc;

       import java.io.IOException;
       import java.io.PrintWriter;
       import java.sql.Connection;   
       import java.sql.DriverManager;
       import java.sql.ResultSet;
       import java.sql.Statement;

       import javax.servlet.ServletException;
       import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;   
       import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
       import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


       public class detailsservlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override 
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {



    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    try{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DSN","scott","krishna");
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from custm");
        pw.println("Id "+ " Name" +" Address" + "<br>");
        while(rs.next())
        {
        pw.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3) + "<br>");
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        pw.println(e);
        }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a doPost method but not doGet method in your sevlet code. If you only want to get information from the jsp page, but not to post any data to the database, then only use doGet. If you want to both post and get, a kind of solution is to

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws  ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(req, res);
}
```

or the other way around, as thats nicer.

Also you shouldnt mix html tags in your Java code.

Another solution to your code is to change your a href="detailssevlet" to a input type button inside a  element, as that will provide a POST to the sever, and not a GET, if thats what you want to do, but not in this case, since you fetch data, not submit it to the server.

Comment: @krishnabhargavi ive now edited the answer. Have you tried the simplest solution to add the doGet method as in the example in this answer from now?

Comment: not the same error now the error is:                               HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Comment: so you changed the a element to a form and an input button element? you had a doPost method already, should have added a doGet. Make sure you have both doGet and doPost, and one of them to delegate to the other one, and redeploy your application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want your `doPost` method to be named `doGet` instead.

Comment: you may have to restart your servlet container to get it to load your recompiled code